# Layout Editor Render error with MapBox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, mapbox

I get the following error when attempting to use the layout editor in Android Studio:

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.widgets.MyLocationView
```

The code works fine, the map is shown. This is a problem strictly with the layout editor.

SSCCE on Github:
https://github.com/emnrd-ito/LayoutEditorRenderProblem
(Note though, that in order to run the code you would need to supply a Map Box access token in `access_token`.)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="testdemo.com.layouteditorrenderproblem.MainActivity">

    <!-- NYC Union Square: 40.73581, -73.99155 -->
    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        mapbox:center_latitude="40.73581"
        mapbox:center_longitude="-73.99155"
        mapbox:style_url="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        mapbox:zoom="17" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:
More info based on answer from @cammace:

Original dependencies:

```
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:1.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Changed to:

```
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.2.1@aar')
```

Still get the error.

Then changed to:

```
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.0-beta.1@aar')
```

I get errors like:

> No resource found that matches the given name (at `textColor` with
>   value @color/black`).

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/about_app_name"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xxl"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project seems to be using an outdated version of our SDK. This issue should be resolved in the latest stable and beta versions. Please upgrade to either `4.2.1` or `5.0.0-beta.1` and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added info based on your answer.

Comment: For some reason, today it works. That is, with 4.1.1 I get the error, with 4.2.2. I don't.